# Chromecast API doesn't accuratelly detect when device is connected/disconnected

Tags: android, ios, chromecast, sender

I have a problem when i am trying to use my chromecast device.
Currently I have an app for Android , one for iOS
and these 2 apps from github.

https://github.com/googlecast/MediaRouter-Cast-Button-android

https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android

All of them have a common problem. They sometimes cannot accuratelly tell if a chromecast device is connected or disconnected.Taking around a minute before they find it out themselfs.While an application like Youtube , discovers if it is connected or not, instantly.

EDIT #1 START:

While using the application "Cast Videos" for android from GitHub the following thing happens.
I hold the android device in my hand (Samsung Galaxy S2). 
I know chromecast is on because I can see it on my monitor.
I start the application "Cast Videos".
The Chromecast icon does not appear, even if the chromecast device is on.

EDIT #1 END;

I have tried using the app_id from my own receiver application , and the default receiver app_id.

I have found a way to trick them into finding the device. By launching the youtube application on an Android or iOS device , connect to the chromecast device , then disconnect.

When I return to on off the apps I have mentioned at the start of the question , they can detect it now , and connect to it.

The two applications from github are not modified , and use the most up to date support libraries (appcompat, mediarouter, CCL).

The applications are now being currently build on a Mac (if that matters). I don't think it will be of any difference if they were built on Windows or something else.

EDIT #2:
I am starting to suspect that actually the wifi router in the building im programming may cause these connection problems. Because when I send the app to other people they don't have the same problem.

EDIT #3:
Good news :D.
The latest update on the castcompanionlibrary made chromecast detection much more reliable and the sample now detects preciselly every time if it is connected or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "hey sometimes cannot accurately tell if a chromecast device is connected or disconnected". Please elaborate on what connectivity you are talking about

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I edited the question a bit, I hope it explains a bit what happens. Maybe I'm just building the applications in a strange way .Applications like Youtube and RedBullTv can detect instantly if a chromecast device is on or off.